# Why does RN Animated.timing toValue of 0 not animate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using `Animated.timing` to apply slide from 0 height animation to an `Animated.View`.

It's exactly like the [jQuery slideDown](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_down) animation.

The problem is when I put a `fromValue` or `toValue` of `0`, it simply ignores the value (and shows full height).

If I put `0.01` it seems to work, but I'm not convinced that's the best solution, maybe just a temporary bandaid...

Does anyone know why it's doing this?

```
_animateIn() {
  Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
    duration: 200,
    toValue: this.props.height,
    fromValue: 0, // works if I put 0.01
  }).start();
};

_animateOut() {
  Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
    duration: 200,
    fromValue: this.props.height,
    toValue: 0, // works if I put 0.01
  }).start();
};

// ...

<Animated.View style={{ height: this.state.height, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
  {children}
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: Works for me, seems like a bug. Which React Native version? Android or iOS?